# Bullet Impact force not working as intended

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I shoot my bullet on a rigid body, it just moves in the wrong direction (to the right, when it is supposed to go forward) Here is the script that handle bullet and target interactions.
I have no idea why this isn't working and help would be appreciated.
thx

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float damage = 10f;
    public float range = 100f;
    public float fireRate = 15f;
    public float impactForce = 200f;
    public ParticleSystem muzzleFlash;

    

    private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;

    public Camera fpsCam;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        muzzleFlash.Play();

        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(fpsCam.transform.position, fpsCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
          Target target =  hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
          

            if (target != null)
            {
                target.TakeDamage(damage);
                hit.rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(transform.forward * impactForce, hit.point); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong transform to get the `forward` vector from.

```
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.TakeDamage(damage);
            hit.rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(transform.forward * impactForce, hit.point); 
        }
```

should be:

```
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.TakeDamage(damage);
            hit.rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(fpsCam.transform.forward * impactForce, hit.point); 
        }
```